# I need help to restart a game in Python

Tags: python

I just don't know how to make a loop and thank you for your help.

```
from random import randint
print ('Bem vindo!')
random = randint(1, 100)
escolha = 0
reiniciar = 0

while escolha!= random:
     escolha = int(input ('Escolha entre 1 e 100: '))

     if escolha == random:
          print ('Venceste!')
     else:
          if escolha > random:
             print ('Alto')
          else:
             print ('Baixo')
print ('Fim do jogo!')
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. Be more precise.

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand the languange but i think you need to change your logic abit:

````
print ('Bem vindo!')

random = randint(1, 100)

escolha = 0

reiniciar = 0

while escolha!= random:

    escolha = int(input ('Escolha entre 1 e 100: '))

    if escolha == random:

        print ('Venceste!')

    elif escolha > random:
        print ('Alto')
    else:
        print ('Baixo')
print ('Fim do jogo!')```
````

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

So you want to create a CLI to your game right? Try to play with while and input functions, and always try to think as the user. Sometimes he doesn't act as we expect.

```
from random import randint

print ('Bem vindo!')

jogar = 'a'

while jogar not in 'nN':
    random = randint(1, 100)
    escolha = 0
    reiniciar = 0


    while escolha!= random:

        escolha = int(input ('Escolha entre 1 e 100: '))

        if escolha == random:
            print ('Venceste!')
        elif escolha > random:
            print ('Alto')
        else:
            print ('Baixo')

    jogar = input('Deseja jogar um novo jogo? (y/n)\n')
    while jogar not in 'nNyY':
        jogar = input('Escolha uma opção válida (y/n)\n')

print ('Fim do jogo!')
```

Saudações Brasileiras!!!!